Styling an element using nth-child
Please see the html below:


.box1 {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.box2,
.box3,
.box4 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
<div class="container1">
  <div class="box1">1a</div>
  <div class="box1">1b</div>
  <div class="box1">1c</div>
</div>

<div class="container2">
  <div class="box2">2</div>
  <div class="box3">3</div>
  <div class="box4">4</div>
</div>



It now looks like this as expected:

.box2, .box3, .box4 {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;  
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

I now want to style box2; box3 and box4 specifically using the pseudo class: nth-child so it looks like this:

I realise I can just add this to the css:
.box2 {
    background-color: yellow;
}

.box3 {
    background-color: green;
}

.box4 {
    background-color: purple;
}

However, I am trying to learn more about pseudo classes and want to use nth-child. I have tried this, which appears to make all of container2 green:
.container2:nth-child(1) {
    background-color: yellow;
}

.container2:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: green;
}

.container2:nth-child(3) {
    background-color: purple;
}

I have also had a look what effect this has (I realise it won't work as there are two div containers):
div:nth-child(1) {
    background-color: yellow;
}

div:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: green;
}

div:nth-child(3) {
    background-color: purple;
}

The result is all over the place.  What am I doing wrong?

You are nearly there. element:nth-child() selects an element that is a specific child which is the wrong selector. You simply need a space between the container and the child selector such as: .container2 :nth-child() and it will work. You can make it shorter by using the Nested CSS module:


[class*="box"] {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.box1 {
  background-color: red;
}

.container2 {
  :nth-child(1) {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  :nth-child(2) {
    background-color: green;
  }
  :nth-child(3) {
    background-color: purple;
  }
}
<div class="container1">
  <div class="box1">1a</div>
  <div class="box1">1b</div>
  <div class="box1">1c</div>
</div>

<div class="container2">
  <div class="box2">2</div>
  <div class="box3">3</div>
  <div class="box4">4</div>
</div>





element:nth-child() selects an element that is a specific child which is the wrong selector.
why are you saying it is wrong ?
why don't you go look up the mdn docs and take a look at the examples there  link


Careful with .container :nth-child(), it will target any nth-child under the container if there's a deeper hierarchy. To only target the immediate children, use .container > :nth-child() instead.

@Hujaakbar because the elements he wants to select are child elements of the container, not the container itself. Reread again instead of posting a link that validates what I was saying.

You missed the HTML tag you want to count. In your case, it's a <DIV> inside a <DIV class="container2">. You made a mistake and put the nt-child in the <DIV class="container2"> itself.


.box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}

.container2 div:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.container2 div:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: green;
}

.container2 div:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: purple;
}
<div class="container1">
  <div class="box">1a</div>
  <div class="box">1b</div>
  <div class="box">1c</div>
</div>
<div class="container2">
  <div class="box">2</div>
  <div class="box">3</div>
  <div class="box">4</div>
</div>




:nth-child() is applied to child elements not a parent element.

The :nth-child() CSS pseudo-class matches elements based on the indexes of the elements in the child list of their parents. In other words, the :nth-child() selector selects child elements according to their position among all the sibling elements within a parent element.

link
You can think of element:nth-child(2) as the element which is the 2nd child of its parent.

To achieve what you wanted, I added bx class to box1, box2, and box3 elements and applied :nth-child() pseudo-class.
Please check below result.


.box1 {
        background-color:red;
        height:100px;
        width:100px;
        margin-bottom:10px;
    }

.box2, .box3, .box4 {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;  
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

.bx:nth-child(1) {
    background-color: yellow;
}

.bx:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: green;
}

.bx:nth-child(3) {
    background-color: purple;
}
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container1">
        <div class="box1">1a</div>
        <div class="box1">1b</div>
        <div class="box1">1c</div>
    </div>

    <div class="container2">
        <div class="box2 bx">2</div>
        <div class="box3 bx">3</div>
        <div class="box4 bx">4</div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>




no need to add a custom class.

@tacoshy there was no requirement as for not to use custom class. I can remove custom class. But anyway you should specify which div element you are referring to, so I used parent container as an identifier.

using the container is correct. All you had to do is add a space between the container selector and the nth-child pseudo-selector. You don't even need to add div which only unnecessarily raises specificity.

so that selector targets the div elements only. In the future code may change and include some p or span elements. Only because you prefer certain style, doesn't mean others' way of doing stuff is wrong.

Where I did say that you were wrong? I just said that it is not necessary to use a div or add a class to achieve what he tried too.
